# .net covariance rules in generics

Tags: c#, generics

I have following code

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface ICriteria<T> where T : class,IEntity
{
    T GetResult(int id);
}

public class DummEntity : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleCriteria<T>:ICriteria<T> where T:class,IEntity
{
    public T GetResult(int id)
    {
        return default(T); 
    }
}
```

should this type casting work ?

```
SimpleCriteria<DummEntity> scr = new SimpleCriteria<DummEntity>();
ICriteria<IEntity> generic = (ICriteria<IEntity>)scr;
```

Comment: If you're interested in how C# 4 deals with variance, see my series of articles on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in C# 3, no. Although the CLR has supported generic variance for interfaces and delegates since .NET 2.0, it hasn't been exposed in C# until version 4.

In C# 4 it will work - but only after you've made `ICriteria<T>` covariant:

```
public interface ICriteria<out T> where T : class,IEntity
{
    T GetResult(int id);
}
```

Note that in C# 3 the explicit cast means that it will *compile* - but it will fail at execution time.

Using C# 4 and the above declaration of `ICriteria<T>`, the conversion is implicit:

```
SimpleCriteria<DummEntity> scr = new SimpleCriteria<DummEntity>();
ICriteria<IEntity> generic = scr;
```

Comment: thanks Jon, is it that the language doesnt implement this feature, or is that my concept of covariance not clear ?

Comment: @ashish: Until C# 4, C# has not supported generic variance.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think it will. scr is of type SimpleCriterial<DummyEntity> yet you're trying to cast it to ICriteria<IEntity> which it is not. Yes, DummyEntity *is* an IEntity, but that's where covariance bites you in the ass.